# Using NMAP to scan local device/own computer

Tags: security, wireshark, nmap

Can't seem to find google-fu info on how to scan your own computer. Alot of guides suggest using your local IP address but i've accidentally just port scanned a foreign internet server.

Is there an option for NMAP to  scan locally or more specifically, how can I scan my device

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solved obscurely

I changed my router address to the usual default and this solved the problem. For anyone thats reading and encounters a similar situation set your Default gateway IP to a standard 192/198 value.

Im not sure how to limit NMAP's scope to just your LAN and so on but this works as it detects the local address first before trying to find it on the internet(DNS resolution).

My problem was my default gateway sharing the same IP as a server, NMAP pinged the foreign server first